# how to add days retrieved from database with a date mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

i have start_date and number_of_days_to _complete stored in database.now i want to echo finish_date by adding this two dynamically.i added a constant date as follows

```
<?php
           $date = strtotime("+7 day");
           echo date('d/m/Y', $date);
 ?>
```

what should be the syntax for my requirement???
i guessed a syntax but it returns wrong date.the format is as follows

```
$date=strtotime("+<?php $row->day_number; ?> day");
echo date('Y-m-d', $date); ?>
```

Comment: Php quotes inside php quotes create problem. Use it as `$date=strtotime("+$row->day_number day");
` https://3v4l.org/j28KF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to this :

```
$requiredDayString = '+'+$row->day_number;
$date=strtotime("$requiredDayString day",strtotime("2016-04-06"));
echo date('Y-m-d', $date); ?>
```

or to make it more dynamic pass as a variable :

```
$requiredDayString = '+'+$row->day_number;
$inputDate = "2016-04-06";
$date=strtotime("$requiredDayString day",strtotime($inputDate ));
echo date('Y-m-d', $date); ?>
```

Comment: for start date 2016-04-06 and day num 4 it gives 2016-06-04

Comment: Try now, in case you want to do for a given date you need to pass the date in strtotim dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You may use DATE_ADD function in MySQL, For Ex

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(now(),INTERVAL 2 DAY) AS resultDate  FROM dual
```